# Getting venueRatingBlacklisted instead of rating

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm using the Foursquare API to get some POI and then am gathering the detailed information of the POI

As an example, I'm using this URL to get details by venue id

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ca1ec1f7ada199c2a5eb3bc?`

However, instead of a rating about the POI there is only this field

`public 'venueRatingBlacklisted' => boolean true`

In the API documentation I can't find any information about this field. When googling this field, I'm just finding some sites that look like spam.

What does this field mean? Why can't I get the rating about that POI? What can I do? Thanks

Comment: I think 'venueRatingBlacklisted' means there is no rating for this venue if this attribute is true.